# Comprobar correo con PHP

Tags: php

Buenas,

Mediante un formulario de registro, recibo entre otras cosas el correo. Para comprobar que sea un correo hago una serie de comprobaciones simples, sin embargo a la hora de intentar encontrar la posición de ciertos caracteres como `@` no me devuelve nada.

```
    $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
    $pos = strpos($mail, "@");
    $pos2 = strpos($mail, ".com");
    $pos3 = strpos($mail, ".es");

    if ($pos == "false" OR $pos2 == "false" OR $pos3 == "false") {
        $errores .= "Correo electrónico no válido </ br>";
    } else {
        if ($mail != $remail) {
            $errores .= "Las contraseñas no coinciden </ br>";
        }
    }
```

El mail lo recibe bien pero en las variables de `$pos` no recibo nada, ni un número ni false. Sé que puedo poner en el tipo de input email, para que compruebe si es un correo, pero prefiero hacerlo de forma manual.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acceder los arreglos superglobales *($_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_SERVER)* directamente, no es algo recomendado en PHP, en su lugar se recomienda usar funciones de *saneo/limpieza* de los datos si lo que necesitas es obtener un valor que llega por POST o GET.

**Primero**

En PHP existe una funcion llamada [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) esta funcion, esta diseñada especificamente, para realizar la "limpieza" de las variables, **pero, solo para aquellas que llegan por POST o GET**, en pocas palabras, esta es la funcion mas **recomendada** para obtener un valor que llega desde el navegador por alguno de estos dos metodos.

**¿Como se usaria?**

Lo primero que deberias hacer, es, realizar un filtrado de la variable que deseas obtener, en este caso `$_POST['mail']` y en su lugar, usar la funcion de la que ya se ha explicado.

Quedando asi:

`$mail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mail");`

**Pero!**, aqui aun no acaba la explicacion. A continuacion podemos usar las diferentes "banderas/flags" que nos permite esta funcion, y una de estas es [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.validate.php), que de acuerdo a la documentacion de PHP:

> Valida una dirección de correo electrónico.

Esta funcion, puede retornarte tres valores.

- NULL : Si la variable `mail` no existe.
- FALSE: Si el correo NO es valido.
- !FALSE : Si el correo es valido, te devuelve el contenido de la variable.

**Conclusion:**

Podrias dejar tu codigo asi:

```
<?php

$mail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mail");

if($mail){
    echo "Correo Electronico valido. <br>";
}
else {
    echo "Correo Electronico NO valido. <br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Gracias a todas las respuestas, esta es la más completa y mejor explicada.

Answer (score 2):

PHP tiene una función para validar email, se llama [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php). Sólo tendrías que enviar tu cadena completa a la función, la cual evalúa si el email está bien escrito.

Ejemplo:

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/QqEAmf)

Aquí lo hago desde una función, pero puedes hacerlo directamente si quieres:

```
$mail = trim($_POST['mail']);

// probando la función
verificarEmail("buen@email.com");
verificarEmail("mal.@email.com");


function verificarEmail ($mail)
{
    if (filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        // bien escrito
        echo $mail. " está bien escrito\n";
    }
    else
    {
        // mal escrito
        echo $mail. " está mal escrito\n";
    }
}
```

**Resultado de la prueba**

> ```
>  buen@email.com está bien escrito 
>
>  mal.@email.com está mal escrito
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Primero ten en cuenta que para verificar un valor false se debe utilizar sin comillas.

Ahora, para realizar lo que quieres hacer hay 2 opciones.

La primera es que al utilizar [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) lo que este te devuelve es un la posición en la que se encuentra la cadena que estas buscando, por lo tanto podrias verificar si es que se encuetran los valores que estas considerando mediante el uso de un if como el siguiente:

**POCO RECOMENDADO**

```
<?php
 $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
 $pos = strpos($mail, "@");
 $pos2 = strpos($mail, ".com");
 $pos3 = strpos($mail, ".es");

 if ($pos > -1 AND ($pos2 > -1 OR $pos3 > -1)) {
    echo "El correo electronico es valido.";
 } else {
    echo "El correo electornico no es invalido";
 }
?>
```

**RECOMENDADO**

La segunda y la recomendada según la documentación de PHP en [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) es que se haga la comprobación mediante el uso de *===* para verificar que realmente se trate de un false booleano. Ademas ten en cuenta que tienes que agrupar la verificacion de los dominios ya que es poco probable que un correo electronico contenga .com y .es .

El codigo recomendado seria:

```
<?php
   $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
   $pos = strpos($mail, "@");
   $pos2 = strpos($mail, ".com");
   $pos3 = strpos($mail, ".es");

   if ($pos === false OR ($pos2 === false AND $pos3 === false)) {
    echo "Correo electrónico no es válido </ br>";
   } else {
    echo "El correo electornico es valido";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes comprobar con la función filter_var() , espero te sea de ayuda.

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

Te dejo el link fuente:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp

Saludos.